# Change color of text as progressbar fills jetpack Compose Android

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-canvas

How to change the color of the text as the progressbar fills in jetpack Compose Android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TPZW.png)

I did tried everything also gradient and also to search on internet , no results

Answer (score 7):

You can easily do this using BlendModes as

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .border(2.dp, Color.Gray, RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .drawWithContent {
            with(drawContext.canvas.nativeCanvas) {
                val checkPoint = saveLayer(null, null)

                // Destination
                drawContent()

                // Source
                drawRect(
                    color = Color.Gray,
                    size = Size(size.width * progress, size.height),
                    blendMode = BlendMode.SrcOut
                )
                restoreToCount(checkPoint)
            }
        }
        .padding(12.dp),
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
) {
    Text(text = "Video starting in 3 seconds", color = Color.Gray, fontSize = 20.sp)
}
```

[image]

just assign a progress parameter and animate it. I made a full implementation

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun ColorProgressBar() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(10.dp)
    ) {

        var target by remember {
            mutableStateOf(0f)
        }

        val progress by animateFloatAsState(
            targetValue = target,
            animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 3000, easing = LinearEasing)
        )
        Button(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            onClick = {
                target = if (target == 0f) 1f else 0f
            }) {
            Text("Start")
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .border(2.dp, Color.Gray, RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .drawWithContent {
                    with(drawContext.canvas.nativeCanvas) {
                        val checkPoint = saveLayer(null, null)

                        // Destination
                        drawContent()

                        // Source
                        drawRect(
                            color = Color.Gray,
                            size = Size(size.width * progress, size.height),
                            blendMode = BlendMode.SrcOut
                        )
                        restoreToCount(checkPoint)
                    }
                }
                .padding(12.dp),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            Text(text = "Video starting in 3 seconds", color = Color.Gray, fontSize = 20.sp)
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .border(2.dp, Color.Gray, RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .drawWithContent {
                    with(drawContext.canvas.nativeCanvas) {
                        val checkPoint = saveLayer(null, null)

                        // Destination
                        drawContent()

                        // Source
                        drawRect(
                            color = Color.Gray,
                            size = Size(size.width * progress, size.height),
                            blendMode = BlendMode.Xor
                        )
                        restoreToCount(checkPoint)
                    }
                }
                .padding(12.dp),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            Text(text = "${(progress * 100).toInt()}%", color = Color.Gray, fontSize = 20.sp)
        }
    }
}
```