# Line with rounded edge on only one side in Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a design for Android where I would need to draw a line with the rounded edge on only one side of the line.

Think a progress bar where both ends of the bar have rounded edges, but it consist of two colors and so that the intersecting part, where the colors change, should not have a rounded edge. My plan is to implement this by drawing two lines of correct length and color where each end has a rounded edge.

Is there some nice way to do it with Jetpack Compose?

I know I can make rounded edges in Compose like this:

```
drawLine(
     start = ..,
     end = ..,
     strokeWidth = 8.dp.toPx(),
     cap = StrokeCap.Round, 
)
```

But this will make both ends of the line rounded, right? Is there some nice way to only round one end of the line?

Edit: Sample picture:
[image]

Comment: Can you add any sample image?

Comment: Yes, of course! I actually found a related question on SO, but for Android views. So added that picture here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Progress bar with one rounded edge

[image]

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun Test2() {

Column {
    var progress by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0f)
    }

    Slider(value = progress, onValueChange = { progress = it })

    Canvas(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .graphicsLayer {
                compositingStrategy = CompositingStrategy.Offscreen
            }
    ) {

        val strokeWidth = 32.dp.toPx()
        val halfStrokeWidth = strokeWidth / 2f

        val width = size.width
        drawLine(
            color = Color.Gray,
            start = Offset(halfStrokeWidth, 100f),
            end = Offset(width - halfStrokeWidth, 100f),
            cap = StrokeCap.Round,
            strokeWidth = strokeWidth
        )

        drawLine(
            color = Color.Red,
            start = Offset(0f, 100f),
            end = Offset(width * (progress), 100f),
            strokeWidth = 32.dp.toPx(),
            blendMode = BlendMode.SrcIn
        )
    }
}
```

}

### Drawing one side Rounded line

extension function of DrawScope that draws 2 lines.

```
 fun DrawScope.drawHorizontalOneEdgeLine(
    color: Color,
    start: Offset,
    end: Offset,
    strokeWidth: Float = Stroke.HairlineWidth,
    cap: StrokeCap = Stroke.DefaultCap,
    pathEffect: PathEffect? = null,
    alpha: Float = 1.0f,
    colorFilter: ColorFilter? = null,
    blendMode: BlendMode = DrawScope.DefaultBlendMode
) {
    drawLine(
        color = color,
        start = start,
        end = end,
        strokeWidth = strokeWidth,
        cap = cap,
        pathEffect = pathEffect,
        alpha = alpha,
        colorFilter = colorFilter,
        blendMode = blendMode
    )

    drawLine(
        color = color,
        start = start.plus(Offset(strokeWidth / 2f, 0f)),
        end = end,
        strokeWidth = strokeWidth,
        cap = StrokeCap.Square,
        pathEffect = pathEffect,
        alpha = alpha,
        colorFilter = colorFilter,
        blendMode = blendMode
    )
}
```

Result

[image]

Demo

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun LineSample() {

    Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        drawLine(
            color = Color.Red,
            start = Offset(100f, 100f),
            end = Offset(700f, 100f),
            cap = StrokeCap.Round,
            strokeWidth = 32.dp.toPx()
        )

        drawHorizontalOneEdgeLine(
            color = Color.Blue,
            start = Offset(100f, 200f),
            end = Offset(700f, 200f),
            cap = StrokeCap.Round,
            strokeWidth = 32.dp.toPx()
        )


        drawLine(
            color = Color.LightGray,
            start = Offset(100f, 1000f),
            end = Offset(1000f, 1000f),
            cap = StrokeCap.Round,
            strokeWidth = 32.dp.toPx()
        )

        drawHorizontalOneEdgeLine(
            color = Color.Green,
            start = Offset(100f, 1000f),
            end = Offset(600f, 1000f),
            cap = StrokeCap.Round,
            strokeWidth = 32.dp.toPx()
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the complete solution with demo!

Comment: @JohanPaul if you wish to create a progressbar using one rounded edged line you should check out my update because drawing lines won't work near or at the edges neither will paths. BlendModes are very powerful to create such Composables. As you can see here same logic used to draw filled rating bar items. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73996333/5457853

Comment: The blend mode makes this approach even cleaner! And nice demo with rating stars!

Comment: Yes. They even work for changing progress as well. That sample is here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75941502/change-color-of-text-as-progressbar-fills-jetpack-compose-android/75942019#75942019

Comment: The progress bar with slider sample did not work out of the box without adding the support for layered drawing. So I took the `drawWithLayer` from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73948960/jetpack-compose-how-to-create-a-rating-bar/73996333#73996333

Comment: You need to call `compositingStrategy = CompositingStrategy.Offscreen` for it work without layer. CompositingStrategy was introduced in Compose 1.4.0-alpha02.

Comment: I use both on based on different situations. Using a layer you can draw some of the items without offscreen buffer as you can see rating bar sample, first items are drawn out of layer. With compostion strategy everything is drawn to buffer and anything outisde of composble bounds is clipped.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I think I had `compositingStrategy = CompositingStrategy.Offscreen` earlier also - but didn't work. Now I tried it again and probably rewrote something else at the same time, and now it works with that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with `drawPath`:

```kotlin
drawPath(
  path = Path().apply {
    addRoundRect(
      RoundRect(
        left = 0F,
        top = 0F,
        right = 200F,
        bottom = 8.dp.toPx(),
        topLeftCornerRadius = CornerRadius(4.dp.toPx(), 4.dp.toPx()),
        bottomLeftCornerRadius = CornerRadius(4.dp.toPx(), 4.dp.toPx()),
        topRightCornerRadius = CornerRadius.Zero,
        bottomRightCornerRadius = CornerRadius.Zero,
      )
    )
  }
)
```